# Get parts of Nodejs Express respond before end() with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would want to get parts of respond from my nodejs server before res.end() with axios, is there a way to do that?
Example :
**Server**

```
router.get('/bulkRes', (req,res)=>{
    res.write("First");
    setTimeout(()=>{
        res.end("Done");
    },5000);
})
```

Example **Client**

```
axios.get("/bulkRes")
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err=> console.log(err))
```

**Expected Result**

```
First
*After 5 second*
Done
```

But what i am getting right now is "First" + "Done" together as a respond after 5 second. I would like to get "First" first then "Done" later after 5 second.

Comment: First of all, what are you trying to achieve? That would be helpful,.

Comment: "I would like to get "First" first then "Done" later after 5 second." Exactly what i asked in the question and getting the console log of the "Expected Result"

Comment: I am trying to load my web app page, but its taking a long time stuck at loading screen because of the images. So i wanna to make a request , get the content first and break the load. Adding all the other images later on.

Comment: Postman or axios() does not support chunking yet,  it waits until it gets the signal the response has ended, Basically, it waits for the entire response before doing something with it. Only browser supports such rendering.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to understand how request and response work. In HTTP on request get one response. so what you want is not achieve using this way.

> You have to use the socket for this scenario

Comment: Thanks , is it a good practice to use web socket just to get a single page of content? I am trying to first load the page content, then the images afterwards. Without requesting multiple times

Comment: So, in this case, the client needs to send a request to the server